# Idle/inactivity tracking with RXJS

Tags: angular-2+, rxjs

I needed to implement a way to track idle state / inactivity in a browser (Angular app), so I tried to create an observable that would trigger whenever there wasn't any user-interaction event, so the client can automatically log out:

```
import {filter, from, fromEvent, mergeAll, Observable, of, repeat, timeout} from 'rxjs';

const timeoutDelay = 1000 * 60 * 5; // 5 minutes
const events = ['keypress', 'click', 'wheel', 'mousemove', 'ontouchstart'];    
const $onInactive = from(events.map(e => fromEvent(document, e)))
  .pipe(
    mergeAll(),
    timeout({each: timeoutDelay, with: () => of(undefined as any)}),
    filter(a => !a),
    repeat()
);
```

And while I was able to make it work with the code above, I'm not sure if this is done correctly for this specific task, so just wanted to double-check here, in case there are any issues with the above solution, like possible bad performance, or unnecessary steps.

The client would be using the above code like this:

```
$onInvactive.subscribe(() => {
    // no user activity for 5 minutes

    // if currently logged in, then log out
});
```

The notification is supposed to arrive whenever inactivity happens, through the lifetime of the web client.